# Can anyone tell me why getTasks() is undefined?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to get tasks from the API, and it returns right, the data is correct and nice.
But when I try to log it to the console, it gives an undefined.
Here is my code:

```
tasksEvents: Task[];


getTasks() {
    this._taskService.getTasks()
    .subscribe(
        res => { this.tasksEvents = res },
        err => console.error(err)
    )
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getTasks();
    console.log(this.getTasks(); <------ Undefined
}
```

As i said, it returns fine the data I want, but I want to do more with `getTasks()`.

Here is the code in `task.service.ts`:

```
taskUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tasks';

getTasks() {
    return this._http.get<Task[]>(this.taskUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getTasks()` is async, you would not be able to log out the underlying emitted values without using a mechanism like `subscribe()` or other RxJS operators like `tap/do` for side effects like logging. Update your code to have `getTasks()` return the observable (remove `subscribe()`) and use `subscribe()` in `ngOnInit()` to set the value of the class property as well as log out the value (if needed):

```
tasksEvents: Task[];

getTasks() {
  return this._taskService.getTasks();
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getTasks().subscribe(res => {
    this.tasksEvents = res;
    console.log(res);
    console.log(this.tasksEvents);
  });
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: It gives me an error: `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.`

Comment: Did you add a `return` statement like `return this._taskService.getTasks()`? What does `_taskService.getTasks` return exactly? Is it an `Observable<Task[]>` or do you `subscribe()` inside there? You should not be putting `subscribe()` inside of task service getTasks(). Updated your question to show exactly how your code looks now please.

Comment: It returns tasks from the server: `return this._http.get<Task[]>(this.taskUrl);`

Comment: Okay, that sounds correct. Please show the updated code exactly how it is now after the changes describe above.

Comment: @AzafoCossa Change `getTasks()` in this component to `getTasks() { return this._taskService.getTasks(); }` just like the answer describes.

Comment: @AzafoCossa You are missing `return` in `getTasks()` of this component